# Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be invariantly valid on 'xxx.IItem<T>.GetList()'. 'T' is covariant

Tags: c#, covariance

Why the following code get the error?

> Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be invariantly valid on
>   'UserQuery.IItem<T>.GetList()'. 'T' is covariant.

```
public interface IFoo {}
public interface IBar<T> where T : IFoo {}

public interface IItem<out T> where T: IFoo
{
    IEnumerable<IBar<T>> GetList();
}
```

Comment: Why did you mark `IItem` as covariant (`out T`) ?

Comment: @Bartosz other part of code need it be covariant

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The interfaces `IBar` and `IItem` do not agree on variance: in your `IBar` declaration, the T is not covariant, as there is no `out` keyword, whereas in `IITem` the T is covariant.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will get rid of the error.

```
public interface IFoo {}
public interface IBar<out T> where T : IFoo {}

public interface IItem<out T> where T: IFoo
{
    IEnumerable<IBar<T>> GetList();
}
```