# The type cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'BaseController<T>'. There is no implicit reference

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, covariance, contravariance

I'm trying to create a generic to simplify my codes (it's a web api project), but at somehow it's ended up becoming more complicated than I expected.  What I'm trying to implement is something like this:

[image: My First Idea]

To simplify my whole real code, this is what I've written:

```
public interface IDatabaseTable { }

public class ReceiptIndex: IDatabaseTable { }

public interface IBackend<T> where T: IDatabaseTable { }

public class Receipts : IBackend<ReceiptIndex> { }

public class Generic<T> : SyncTwoWayXI, IBackend<T> where T:IDatabaseTable { }

public class BaseController<T> : ApiController where T: IBackend<IDatabaseTable>, new () { }
```

All of the line above created separately in its own file.

When I try to create controller that Inherit from BaseController

```
public class ReceiptsBaseController : BaseController<Receipts>
```

I get an error said

> The type 'Receipts' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the
>   generic type or method 'BaseController'. There is no implicit
>   reference conversion from 'Receipts' to 'IBackend'.

I try to find a similar problem and end up with something called Covariance and Contravariance problem. Can anyone give feedback for what I'm trying to do or maybe something that can I do to simplify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to specify the `T` in IBackend.
Like this:

```
public class BaseController<T, TBackEndSubType> : ApiController
    where T : IBackend<TBackEndSubType>, new()
    where TBackEndSubType : IDatabaseTable { }

public class ReceiptsBaseController : BaseController<Receipts, ReceiptIndex> { }
```

Comment: I try this solution; it solves the error problem. But at somehow when I create a controller inherited ```BaseController``` class, it isn't registered as valid API endpoint.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to solve this, without using covariance and contravariance, which has some important implications, is this:

```
public class BaseController<TBackend, TDatabaseTable>
    : ApiController
    where TBackend : IBackend<TDatabaseTable>, new() 
    where TDatabaseTable: IDatabaseTable
{ }
```

And use it in this way

```
public class ReceiptsBaseController : BaseController<Receipts, ReceiptIndex>
{
}
```

The syntax is not so compact, but it works like a charm, without the extra implications of covariance or contravariance.

Answer (score 0):

On the BaseController you have this condition:

```
where T: IBackend<IDatabaseTable>
```

but receipts inhertits IBackend<ReceiptIndex>, which is not directly compatible with IBackend<IDatabaseTable>. You could add 2 generic parameters on your BaseController:

```
public class BaseController<TBackend, TDatabaseTable> : ApiController 
    where TDatabaseTable: IDatabaseTable 
    where TBackend: IBackend<TDatabaseTable>, new () { }
```

then you can declare your controller like this:

```
public class ReceiptsBaseController : BaseController<Receipts, ReceiptIndex>
```

Answer (score 0):

using the out modifier: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx

Change the IBackend interface to look like this:

```
 public interface IBackend<out T> where T : IDatabaseTable { }
```

Comment: I have tried it, but it turns out make one of method declaration on my interface error.

`Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be invariantly valid on 'Backend.Objects.IBackend<T>.GetItem(string, long)'. 'T' is covariant.
`

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12484293/invalid-variance-the-type-parameter-t-must-be-invariantly-valid-on-xxx-iitem

Comment: The link you mention above suggest that I should remove the ```setter``` on the return object properties, that's kind of impossible for my requirement, because I still need a ```setter``` on my method return object

Comment: @MartinDavidValentinoSiagian, The link I sent was saying that you need to apply the out modifier to other interfacesas well and not just in the IBackend<> interface.