# Parsing Enum to Enum when implementing FlagsAttribute

Tags: c#, enums, attributes, .net-4.7.2

I have two questions, one deriving from the other.

1. I'm trying to parse an Enum that has the `FlagsAttribute` attribute to another enum which also has the same attribute. My attempt is in the code below. If someone has found an efficient way of doing this please let me know. As my current method involves iterating for all set flags and parsing one by one and then logically OR'ing them together.
2. In attempting to solve this I got this error: 
   `The type 'Program.Test' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Program.Parse<T>(string, bool)'. There is no boxing conversion from 'Program.Test' to 'System.FlagsAttribute'.` What I'm really looking for here is an explanation as to why. Obviously both enums have the `Flags` attribute which is shorthand for `FlagsAttribute` so shouldn't there already exist a conversion?

Also link for the lazy : [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jy8CtR)

Code:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var q = Parse<TestType>((Test.ACT | Test.SAT_2016).ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Type: {0}\t Value: {1}", q.GetType(), q));

    // */

}

public static T Parse<T>(string value, bool ignoreCase = false)
    where T : FlagsAttribute , IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
{
    if (value.ToString().Contains(",")){
        var parts = value.ToString().Split(',');
        var results = new List<T> ();
        var final = default(T);

        foreach (var part in parts){
            try {
                final |= (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), part, ignoreCase) ;
            }catch (Exception e){
                Console.WriteLine("Got exception");
                /* Supressed */
            }
        }
        return final;

    }else{
        return (T) Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value.ToString(), ignoreCase);
    }
}
[Flags]
public enum Test{
    ACT = 32,
    SAT_2016 = 65536,
};
[Flags]
public enum TestType {
    ACT = 4,
    SAT_2016 = 39,
};
```

Comment: How about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30186261/the-type-cannot-be-used-as-type-parameter-t-in-the-generic-type-or-method-bas

Comment: Also you can try the where T : new() which loosens generic restrictions. I am not sure this is what you need though.

Comment: Also this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum

Comment: You don't have to call `ToString` on `value` as it's already a `string`.  Also instead of checking for the comma you can just use the code that splits the string as that will work even if there is no comma (it would return an array that contains just the original string).  If not you don't catch the potential exception when parsing a value that doesn't contain a comma.

Answer (score 1):

Your enum *has the `[Flags]` attribute*; it doesn't *inherit* from `FlagsAttribute` - so just remove the `T : FlagsAttribute` constraint.

In C# 7.3 or above, you can just use the `where T : Enum` constraint directly; there is no way of expressing "has a specific attribute" in a generics constraint - you'd have to check that via reflection at runtime.

Comment: That takes care of the exception, and I guess it makes sense that it doesn't implement the `FlagsAttribute` class, but that still doesn't allow me to logically or together the results. Since I'm not on C# 7.3 I have replaced the FlagsAttribute with the struct which is what I initially was using.